# Expo with create-react-native-app; inconsistent behaviour

Tags: react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

I work on a project started through CRNA (create-react-native-app) and I usually do

1. yarn start
2. Open project on Expo XDE
3. Device > Open on Android (which starts it in my Android simulator (NoxPlayer)

However, since 2 days ago, it's been on the "Building JavaScript bundle..." and is EXTREMELY slow (we're talking 2-3 hrs) before it just stagnates and stops progressing. (I tried rolling back to old branches that worked and the same problem was present.)

I tried started a new clean slate project... Sometimes it works perfectly, sometimes it has the same slow build problem, sometimes it simply won't connect to the tunnel; an inconsistent behaviour.

Any ideas on how to debug this or any similar alternative to Expo?